Logic Apps: How to save file from email onto sharepoint
In the below workflow, when an email arrives I want it to save the contents into a SharePoint folder. The workflow is successful, however the file becomes broken/ does not work because attachments content is a giant hash. There is nothing wrong with the file.


I got the same error when i used attachment content directly in the "create file" action. These series of steps helped in accessing the content:

Use "Get folder metadata using path" action. I specified the file within the folder path as well such that the folder path encompasses the attachment name within the folder path.


This is obviously going to fail but we'll handle this error through a scope function.


Use the "Scope" function to check if the attachment exists setting the prev action has failed as a requirement. Once it has failed, it will create the attachment within the specified folder path, file name and file content.

This step includes 2 additional steps prior to creating the file and is mainly done through (1) getting the folder metadata (2) error handling through a scope function.

